# Drive bay not working when empty on startup

Tags: boot, hard-drive, drive, fdisk, sata

I have a SATA drive bay, which only works when having a drive inserted at startup. If I start the system and then enter a drive, it starts running (makes sounds and is vibrating), but it won't even show up in `sudo fdisk -l`.

However, if I'm starting the system with a drive inserted, I can remove it while the system runs, it disappears from `fdisk`, insert it again, and it reappears and is usable.

I think that the drive is „dumb”, meaning there is no controller or whatsoever involved, directly connecting the drive to the mainboard.

Is this issue related to the mainboard, or is it possible to use the bay without a disk inserted at boot time? Are those bays maybe not even designed to hot swap drives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I supposed you SATA controlled/ motherboard supports hot-plug and you are using Debian/Ubuntu system.

To force a rescan on scsi ( each sata port apperas as a scsi bus), you must write "0 0 0" in each hostX controller in `/sys/class/scsi_host/host<X>/scan`
(you must be root user)

How to do it on all hosts:

```
for i in `ls /sys/class/scsi_host/` ; do echo "0 0 0" > /sys/class/scsi_host/$i/scan ; done ;
```

Verify that `/var/log/kern.log` shows the new device like this:

```
Mar  1 11:27:48 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [ 8307.445629] ata2: hard resetting link
Mar  1 11:27:49 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [ 8307.762354] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Mar  1 11:27:49 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [ 8307.763572] ata2.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
Mar  1 11:27:49 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [ 8307.763579] ata2.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
Mar  1 11:27:49 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [ 8307.763583] ata2.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
Mar  1 11:27:49 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [ 8307.766011] ata2.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
Mar  1 11:27:49 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [ 8307.766025] ata2.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
Mar  1 11:27:49 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [ 8307.766033] ata2.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
Mar  1 11:27:49 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [ 8307.766834] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
Mar  1 11:27:49 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [ 8307.782363] ata2: EH complete
Mar  1 11:27:49 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [ 8307.783079] ata5: hard resetting link
Mar  1 11:27:49 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [ 8308.102607] ata5: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
Mar  1 11:27:49 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [ 8308.107447] ata5.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
Mar  1 11:27:49 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [ 8308.107455] ata5.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
Mar  1 11:27:49 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [ 8308.107458] ata5.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
Mar  1 11:27:49 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [ 8308.123863] ata5.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
Mar  1 11:27:49 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [ 8308.123870] ata5.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
Mar  1 11:27:49 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [ 8308.123874] ata5.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
Mar  1 11:27:49 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [ 8308.129772] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/100
Mar  1 11:27:49 gilito-MS-AF1511 kernel: [ 8308.142581] ata5: EH complete
```

Then, run `fdisk -l` to see the new disk

Comment: `motherboard supports hot-plug` - that was actually the most helpful part, I had to enable hot plugging support in the UEFI for the desired port (Gigabyte GA-Z77X-D3H). Thanks!